# why password field gets empty on click of back and forward on browser

Tags: html

We have a login/ registration form. I filled all the fields username, first name, last name and password.

Now I clicked on back button from browser and again clicked on forward. All information is there except password field.

Password field gets empty.
I know its a default property of password field but i need the reason.

Can anyone help on this.?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could show us some of your code so we can see what you did there.

Comment: <form>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
User password:<br>
<input type="password" name="psw">
</form>

Comment: I want to say that this is default for security purposes. You wouldn't want someone coming behind you and navigating to a previously viewed page and be able to get that information somehow. (Ofcourse that is just my thoughts, I do no know for sure).

Comment: @Shadow Codex is right...

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour, as someone could come along, click back and then use a tool to show the password behind the *'s